# Angular 5, Set Component's Template From Database, And Render Context Data

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to load a component's template dynamically from database, what I have is the following HTML Template

```
<h1>{{tname}}</h1>
```

I tried two methods one mentioned in [Angular official Doc](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) and second using `createEmbeddedView()` called on `ViewContainerRef` I do get the template results with`h1` tag applied but the template is not rendered. I get **{{tname}}**

I have inside the component's template:

```
<div #target></div>
<ng-template #template>
    <div [innerHTML]="templateString"></div>
</template>
```

I also tried:

```
<div #target></div>
<ng-template #template let-tname="fromContext">
    <div [innerHTML]="templateString"></div>
</template>
```

My questions are:

- How would I render the template, with supplied data?
- Can I set the Component's template dynamically i.e the value of template supplied to the `@Component` decorator?

**Edit**
Component's Code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-print-receipt-template-preview',
  templateUrl: './print-receipt-template-preview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./print-receipt-template-preview.component.scss']
})
export class PrintReceiptTemplatePreviewComponent implements OnInit {
   private _tmp:string;
   private _data:any;

   @Input()
   set template(v:string) {
     if (v) {
       this._tmp = v;
       this.initTemplate()
     }
   }

   get template() {
     return this._tmp;
   }

   @Input()
   set saleData(v:any) {
     this._data = v;
   }

   get saleData() {
     return this._data;
   }

   @ViewChild('receiptContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) private target: ViewContainerRef;

   @ViewChild('template',{read: TemplateRef}) private tmp: TemplateRef<any>;

   constructor(private componentResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

   initTemplate() {
     // let cmp = PrintReceiptTemplateComponent;
     // let fac = this.componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(cmp);
     this.target.clear();
     let componentRef = this.target.createEmbeddedView(this.tmp, {saleData: this._data});
     // let instance:any = componentRef.instance;
     // instance.data = this._data;
    // instance.template = this._tmp;
   }
}
```

Comment: can you share your component code?

Comment: Please see the edited question, I have added the code.

Comment: Have you looked at the answer on this SO post where they show how to create a dynamic component with a dynamic template supplied? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular

Comment: Thank you @DanielWStrimpel for the link solved it with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42065289/7852595

Comment: Ok, yeah that was the answer I was thinking of. Nice